Items are not updating and not added to cart
Can't add items to cart or update counts for Mango web page.
I tried a lot of code, even chat gpt and any other AI. But I'm still stuck.
My github link: https://github.com/Thibaut501/Mango
Can someone tell me where is the error?
It is on Visual Studio 2022. It is an ASP.NET Core MVC project based on micro services.
using Mango.Web.Models;
using Mango.Web.Service;
using Mango.Web.Service.IService;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace Mango.Web.Controllers
{
    public class CartController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICartService _cartService;
        private readonly IOrderService _orderService;
        private readonly ILogger<CartController> _logger; // Add logger
        
        public CartController(ICartService cartService, IOrderService orderService, ILogger<CartController> logger)
        {
            _cartService = cartService;
            _orderService = orderService;
            _logger = logger; // Assign logger
        }

        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CartIndex()
        {
            return View(await LoadCartDtoBasedOnLoggedInUser());
        }

        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout()
        {
            return View(await LoadCartDtoBasedOnLoggedInUser());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Checkout")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(CartDto cartDto)
        {
            CartDto cart = await LoadCartDtoBasedOnLoggedInUser();

            if (cart != null)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Updating cart with item count: {Count}", cart.CartDetails?.Count()); // Log the cart item count
            }

            cart.CartHeader.Phone = cartDto.CartHeader.Phone;
            cart.CartHeader.Email = cartDto.CartHeader.Email;
            cart.CartHeader.Name = cartDto.CartHeader.Name;

            var response = await _orderService.CreateOrder(cart);

            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Order successfully created for user ID: {UserId}", cart.CartHeader.UserId);
                // Proceed with Stripe session or order confirmation
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Order creation failed for user ID: {UserId}", cart.CartHeader.UserId);
            }

            return View(cart);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Confirmation(int orderId)
        {
            return View(orderId);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Remove(int cartDetailsId)
        {
            var userId = User.Claims.Where(u => u.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
            ResponseDto? response = await _cartService.RemoveFromCartAsync(cartDetailsId);
            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                TempData["success"] = "Cart updated successfully";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(CartIndex));
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ApplyCoupon(CartDto cartDto)
        {
            ResponseDto? response = await _cartService.ApplyCouponAsync(cartDto);
            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                TempData["success"] = "Cart updated successfully";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(CartIndex));
            }
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveCoupon(CartDto cartDto)
        {
            cartDto.CartHeader.CouponCode = "";
            ResponseDto? response = await _cartService.ApplyCouponAsync(cartDto);
            if (response != null & response.IsSuccess)
            {
                TempData["success"] = "Cart updated successfully";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(CartIndex));
            }
            return View();
        }

        private async Task<CartDto> LoadCartDtoBasedOnLoggedInUser()
        {
            var userId = User.Claims.Where(u => u.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
            ResponseDto? response = await _cartService.GetCartByUserIdAsnyc(userId);
            if (response != null && response.IsSuccess)
            {
                CartDto cartDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CartDto>(Convert.ToString(response.Result));
                return cartDto;
            }
            return new CartDto();
        }
    }
}

Only the Cart items are not adding when add to cart, coupons is displaying but not applied or remove, and items count not updating also on CartIndex page.
Please help find the solution.
Thank you,
Fabrice

You need to POST the relevant snippets of code and markup here - not just a link to a github repo ....

_logger.LogInformation Please let us know which log entries are written.

I found all the service for calling the api contains the  Console.WriteLine($"Service Layer Response: {response?.Result}"); , what's the response. result?

Updating cart with item count: {Count}", cart.CartDetails?.Count()); // Log the cart item count
}

Is that the only log entry written?

no,can someone help,I'm stuck with this program.

What was the other log entry written? (And yes, I'll keep repeating the same question until you fully answer it)

Hi,discount remains zero.else appear .Any urgent help,
